OSError when using pyiceberg with Hive Metastore on OpenShift - SSL peer certificate issue
I have an OpenShift cluster hosting Trino and Iceberg tables in Minio s3 buckets. I'm working on a feature to upload files using the pyiceberg library. For development, I'm using oc port-forward svc/metastore-hive 8087:9083 to connect to the Hive Metastore.
Here is the relevant part of my code:
from pyiceberg.catalog.hive import HiveCatalog

catalog = HiveCatalog(
    "docs",
    uri="thrift://localhost:8087",
    warehouse=TRINO_HOST,
    s3_endpoint=S3_HOST,
    py_io_impl="pyiceberg.io.pyarrow.PyArrowFileIO",
    s3_access_key_id=S3_ACCESS_KEY,
    s3_secret_access_key=S3_SECRET_KEY,
)

print('catalog', catalog.list_namespaces())

table = catalog.load_table(f'{schemaname}.{tablename}')

Printing namespaces works, but when loading table I am getting OSError

OSError: When reading information for key
'data_raw/table-c1ba9c3550e743aeac7f56d7fab020a3/metadata/03973-2502845d-50df-40e6-bbd6-7c4a8f00e685.metadata.json'
in bucket 'data-bucket': AWS Error NETWORK_CONNECTION during
HeadObject operation: curlCode: 60, SSL peer certificate or SSH remote
key was not OK

It seems to be an SSL certificate issue. Firstly it would be fine just to ignore secure connections. Has anyone faced a similar problem or can provide guidance on how to resolve this?

you want to change s3 bucket url in https into http. i think so it wil work
